# Springboot statc content : None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin, static-content

I'm running a springboot jar application, and I'm facing some issues accessing static content from it.
I placed my static content under src/main/resources/static and it is getting copied to the jar as BOOT-INF/classes/static .
But I see this log message on startup -

> TomcatServletWebServerFactory : None of the document roots
> [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be
> ignored.

Jar contents :

[image]

Tried accessing as - /static/js/myjs.js , /js/myjs.js - no luck ?

Do I need any extra configuration for this ?